# Regex.Match Parameter Possible?

Tags: c#

Good Day,

I have some HTML input that I want to do a search and replace operation.

```
string html = @"
    <div class=""left bottom-margin"">
    <input id=""0086"" maxlength=""29"" data-src=""200:80"" type=""text""><br />
    <input id=""0087"" maxlength=""38"" data-src=""201:80"" type=""text""><br />
    <input id=""0088"" maxlength=""38"" data-src=""202:80"" type=""text""><br />
</div>";    

// Here we call Regex.Match.
Match match = Regex.Match(html, @"(<input.*id=""0087"".*?>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Here we check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
{
    // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("No Match...");
}
```

This code does work, so far, but I want to be able to provide a parameter to the Regex.Match initialization.  Is this possible?  What if I wanted to search for 0086 or 0088 as the id?  I have a couple hundred tags like this where I want to be able to find the HTML tag by providing a parameter?

I understand that the @ makes the string verbatim.

But I've tried doing this:

```
// string pattern = "(<input.*id=\"\"0087\"\".*?>)";
// string pattern = "(<input.*id=\"\"" + "0087" + "\"\".*?>)";
```

This doesn't work either.  Most of the Regex.Match samples I've seen use the @ verbatim symbol to do the actual matching.  Is my understanding of this correct?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have pairs of escaped double-quotes in `"(<input.*id=\"\"" + "0087" + "\"\".*?>)"`? This will result in a regex pattern `(<input.*id=""0087"".*?>)` - certainly not what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
string pattern = String.Format(@"(<input.*id=""{0}"".*?>)", "0087");
```

It looks like it works fine for me.

Actually, even this works as well:

```
string pattern = @"(<input.*id=""" + "0087" + @""".*?>)";
```

Comment: I guess that's what happens when you haven't had much sleep in one day.  So close and yet so far.  thanks, mate.

Answer (score 1):

You can't supply a parameter to a regular expression. But you could...Not try to coerce regular expressions into being an HTML parser.

- If your document contains valid markup, you can load it into a suitable XMLDocument and apply the desired tranformations in any of a number of different ways:

  - either programatically using XPATH queries
  - by traversing the document to find the nodes you're interested in,
  - applying an XSLT transformation.
  - using Linq for XML
- OR you could install the [HTML Agility Pack via NuGet](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), load your document into an `HTmlDocument` and use its transformation capabilities.

If you're determined to use regular expression, you can

- Build your regular expression on the fly, something like

  ```
  Regex ConstructRegex( int id )
  {
    string pattern = string.format( @"(<input.*id=""{0:0000}"".*?>)" , id ) ;
    Regex instance = new Regex( pattern ) ;
    return instance
  }
  ```
- Make your regular expression generic and supply a `MatchEvaluator`/`Func<Match,string>` to apply the desired transformations to each match (if required):

  ```
  static readonly Regex rx = new Regex( @"(<input.*id=""(?<id>\d\d\d\d)"".*?>)" ) ;

  string Transform( string html , Func<string,string> transform )
  {
    string transformed = rx.Replace( html, transform ) ;
    return transformed ;
  }
  ```

  Which you could use thus:

  ```
  string raw    = "some html here" ;
  string cooked = Transform( raw , m => {
      int id = int.Parse( m.Groups["id"].Value ) ;
      string s = Match.Value ;
      if ( id == 86 )
      {
        s = apply_some_transformation_here(m.Value) ;
      }
      return s ;
    }) ;
  ```